# postgresql change varchar to integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to convert column type from varchar to integer  in postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE billdetail ALTER COLUMN  masterid TYPE integer;
```

gives

```
[Err] ERROR:  column "masterid" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING masterid::integer".
```

while

```
   ALTER TABLE billdetail USING masterid::integer;
```

gives

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE billdetail USING masterid::integer;
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try,

```
ALTER TABLE billdetail 
        ALTER COLUMN masterid TYPE INT USING masterid::integer;
```

You forgot to alter the column.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE INT USING col_name::integer;`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**